# max-age and httponly cookie attributes not appearing in the response header

Tags: karate

we want the responseHeader returns the following as in the postman, but the max-age and other items in it missing.

we want the responseHeader returns the following as in the postman: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iyzF.png), but from karate, it returns:

```
1 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
1 < Set-Cookie: qbn.ptc.agentid=; Domain=intuit.ca; Secure
1 < Set-Cookie: qbn.ptc.authid=; Domain=intuit.ca; Secure
1 < Set-Cookie: qbn.ptc.gauthid=; Domain=intuit.ca; Secure
1 < Set-Cookie: qbn.ptc.parentid=; Domain=intuit.ca; Secure
1 < Set-Cookie: qbn.ptc.ticket=; Domain=intuit.ca; Secure
1 < Set-Cookie: qbn.ptc.tkt=; Domain=intuit.ca; Secure
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to work in 1.3.1 and 1.4.0.RC3: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2165

If not, follow this process so that we can fix it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue